# Download password protected, compressed file with Python

Tags: python, download, urllib2

I am trying to figure out how to use python to download a compressed file that is on a password protected site. Here is what I have but it doesn't work.

```
import urllib2
pwmgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
tlurl = "https://abc.def.ghi.com"
pwmgr.add_password(None, tlurl, "username", "password")
handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(pwmgr)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(handler)
response = opener.open("https://abc.def.ghi.com/page/page2/t1/full/file.tbz")
thisfile = open("file.tbz","wb")
output.write(response.read())
output.close()
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What happens?

Comment: Also, are you sure the site uses HTTP Basic auth and not Digest, or some kind of site-internal login instead of HTTP auth? (And if you think you're sure, did you determine that by knowing the server configs, proxying a web browser, using a browser add-on, or some other means?)

Comment: Finally: Every question on this site about urllib2 is guaranteed to get three people saying "Don't use urllib2, [requests](http://python-requests.org) is cooler." Usually they're being silly, because the problem is one where the urllib2 code looks and works just as simple as the requests code. This time, they're right. HTTP auth is one of the things that requests makes _much_ easier to write, and to debug.